# Does Dungeon Siege 3 support USB gamepad controllers?

Tags: pc, controllers, dungeon-siege-3

I've played through Dungeon Siege 3's demo, and I couldn't ever get a good handle on the movement controls; I found movement cumbersome, and (no doubt to weeks of playing League of Legends) kept expecting <kbd>Q</kbd> to activate my abilities (it toggled my stance instead).

It's clear from the demo that the game was developed for a console control scheme; I have a USB Gamepad that I bought to play Super Meat Boy -- is it possible to play Dungeon Siege 3 with a Gamepad as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: Applies to Demo only. The full game appears to require xbox360 controllers!!**

Originally, I had attempted to plug in my USB gamepad while the Dungeon Siege 3 demo was already running; this did not allow me to play the game with the gamepad. However, today I tried again, but this time plugged in the gamepad *before* running the program, and it allowed me to use the gamepad for everything.

So yes, Dungeon Siege 3 is wholly compatible with USB gamepads.

Comment: Hi can you tell me what gamepad you are using?

Comment: @Henry I believe it's an [F310 Gamepad](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/gaming/controllers/devices/7360) by Logitech